# scale object size viewport-> preview

Tags: vb.net, scaling

I toying with a project where I can position objects runtime on the screen. I also have an small "preview"-window, where I want to see the outline of the objects.

I have an object array who have size and location on the "scene". Now I want to loop through my scene-objects and create one picturebox in the preview-window for each object in the "scene".

So, I have the size of the "Scene" and an array of the objects that are visible on the scene. Every object have an size and location mapped to the scene.

I also have a preview window that have an dynamic size. How do I create a preview that scales down to the preview window? To make it easy, I loop through the scene objects in the scene and create a picturebox on the preview-form for each object, that uses the preview-forms size to do the scaling.

```
SceneSize=new size(800,600) 
PreviewSize=new size(80,60) 

For each obj as SceneObject in Scene
   dim p as new picturebox
    p.size=?? scaling here (we have obj.size and obj.location)
    p.location=?? scaling here (we have obj.size and obj.location)
    previewWindow.controls.add (p)

next
```

Any example in .Net would be nice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick, it wasn't harder than that.

```
Function GetPreviewRectangleForObject(ByVal ScreenSize As Size, ByVal PreviewSize As Size, ByVal OriginalRect As Rectangle) As Rectangle
    Dim xFactor As Integer = ScreenSize.Width / PreviewSize.Width
    Dim yFactor As Integer = ScreenSize.Height / PreviewSize.Height
    With OriginalRect
        Return New Rectangle(.X / xFactor, .Y / yFactor, .Width / xFactor, .Height / yFactor)
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Bob Powell's site on GDI+ might have some useful information on how to proceed. Check out his page on Matrix Transformations. This article might provide you with some good ideas on how to proceed

[Bob Powell GDI+ Transformations](https://web.archive.org/web/20130312094930/http://www.bobpowell.net/transformations.htm)